# How do I control the alignment of formatted text in Java?

Tags: java

I'm knocking my head here using System.out.printf and I really don't understand something that seems that it should be much more simple.

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double dog  = 3.85;
        double cat = 333.85;
        System.out.printf("Hola:%7.1f\n",dog);
        System.out.printf("Hola:%5.0f", cat);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand what the significance is of the numbers after the percentage symbol. In short in the line:

```
System.out.print("Number: %x.y", someNumber);
```

what does the x tell me and what does the y tell me?

Comment: Look up the [Formatting Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) for the basics and the the [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class in the Java API for the details. It's all explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- x = minimum width of how many digits are displayed to the left of the decimal with padding.
- y = precision of floating point numbers to the right of the decimal.

Comment: actually this doesn't seem right. according to what you have said if I set x=2 and then do System.out.printf("%2.2f", cat); then I would print out 33.85, however it still prints out 333.85 when I run that.

Comment: Updated to clarify what width means.